# How to SELECT from database with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to execute this code, the site goes offline. Can you help me fix the code, since I cannot get it to work? :( I have managed to set up update and insert queries.

**Get.php**

```
case "callfromotherfile":

        $getcat = new Test();
        echo json_encode( $getcat->getCategories(); );
        break;
```

**Test.php**

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = ASDatabase::getInstance();
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        $query = ("SELECT name FROM categories");
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement[];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
How to fetch?

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'Get.php', 
      action: 'callfromotherfile',                                                          
      dataType: 'json',               
      success: function(data)          
      {
        console.log(data);
        var id = data[0];             
        var vname = data[1];        
      }
    });
```

Comment: For one thing you have a syntax error here: `return $statement[];`. I recommend you make sure your PHP interpreter is displaying errors.

Comment: Here is a [good place to start reading](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return the database connection object, and you haven't fetched the results, try doing this instead of your current `getCategories()` function

```
public function getCategories() {

    $query = ("SELECT name FROM categories");

    $statement = $this->db-> prepare($query);

    $statement -> execute();

    $results = $statement->fetchAll();

    return $results
}
```